# Apply Script on Gradle to private (enterprise) github repo using personal access token

Tags: github, gradle

I have a centralized gradle script stored on a private github repo (actually an enterprise repo).

I can apply the plugin if I put the url in with a session token at the end.

The problem is the session token expires in  7 days.

There is an option to use a personal access token but the only way to use the personal access token is through a curl command.

I have tried several variations of the curl command in the apply from command and none of them work. Is there a way to do this in gradle?

I have scoured the internet to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to solve this is to run the curl command as an exec inside the buildscript block. This causes the exec command to get run before the configuration step begins. So the file is available during the configuration step.

example:

```
buildscript {
 exec {
  workingDir projectDir
  commandLine "curl","-s","-O","https://(Token)@raw.github.com/path to file"
 }
}

apply from: "${projectDir}/other.gradle"
```